# Obtener 2 input con mismo name

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de obtener por name  2 `inputs` que genera por jQuery un select (por eso el contador) luego hacer un `REQUEST`  en ajax con un `foreach`  que recorra input por input para así hacer el save, el problema es que me obtiene los 2 values de los input  al mismo tiempo:

```js
function guardarDescripcion() {
    var inclusions1 = '';
    var incCount = document.getElementsByName("inclusions1[]").length;
    for(i=0;i<incCount;i++){
        inclusions1 = + inclusions1 document.getElementsByName("inclusions1[]")[i].value; 
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_save.php",
        data: "&inclusions1=" + inclusions1, 
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function () {     
            alert("Datos guardados exitosamente");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error al guardar el opcional.");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="inclusions1[]" class="form-control " value="TEST1" style="width: 246px; margin: 4px 0px;">
<input type="text" name="inclusions1[]" class="form-control "  value="TEST2" style="width: 246px; margin: 4px 0px;">

<button type="button" onclick="guardarDescripcion();">Save</button>
```

Comment: nope, no se entiende, dime tu quieres hacer un ajax por cada input? o quieres hacer un ajax con varios atributos ?

Comment: un ajax con varios atributos , osea obtener en el ajax los 2 input enviados por GET , la idea es esa , el tema es que envia solo el valor de un input o si no me envia el valor de los dos input en un solo string . al hacer un  dump por ajax me imprime por ejemplo TEST1TEST2 juntos , como podria hacer para enviarlos en diferentes string?

Comment: ok ahora mi pregunta es como lo vas a leer, leerás muchos atributos (esto implica que cada atributo debe tener un nombre de atributo, no pueden llamarse todos "inclusions1") o quieres enviarlos todos en un arreglo

Comment: has probado a serializarlos? `$("[name='inclusions1[]']").serialize()`

Comment: El tema es que hay una funcion aparte de un select que por seleccion va creando inputs con name inclusions1[] (todos) , No tengo posibilidad de cambiar el name de cada input

Comment: Lo he intentado Dibort pero nada , No encuentro solucion alguna

Comment: creo que no me entendiste la pregunta, a lo que voy yo es... quieres una url que se vea así? `ajax_save.php?inclusions1=valor1,valor2,valor3` o una url que se vea así `ajax_save.php?inclusions1=valor1&inclusions2=valor2&inclusions3=valor3`

Comment: aah!! lo ideal seria  `ajax_save.php?inclusions1=valor1,valor2,valor3`  yo despues separo por `br` en foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta tu último comentario, puedes colocar tus valores en un array, luego enviarlo por GET:

```js
function guardarDescripcion() {
    var inclusions1 = [];
    var incCount = document.getElementsByName("inclusions1[]").length;
    for(i=0;i<incCount;i++){
        inclusions1[i] = document.getElementsByName("inclusions1[]")[i].value; 
    };
    console.log("Array: " + inclusions1); //
    console.log("Para el request GET: " + inclusions1.toString());
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_save.php",
        data: "&inclusions1=" + inclusions1.toString(), //a String
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function () {     
            alert("Datos guardados exitosamente");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error al guardar el opcional.");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="inclusions1[]" class="form-control " value="TEST1" style="width: 246px; margin: 4px 0px;">
<input type="text" name="inclusions1[]" class="form-control "  value="TEST2" style="width: 246px; margin: 4px 0px;">

<button type="button" onclick="guardarDescripcion();">Save</button>
```

Comment: Gracias hermano funciono perfectamente !! un abrazo enorme!